# how to display data from self created array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-blade

I create an array for the blade view. Collect the data from table and store in an array, `$post_data`. For laravel generated array, `foreach` loop will do the job. But, it seems a different things with self created array. Please help.

I use 2 `foreach` because the array consist of 2 dimensional array.

[The result of `dd($post_data)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsnTj.png)
[The result of `var_dump($data)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u78ob.png)
[The result of `var_dump($item)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GY0Q.png)

> ERROR: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

**Controller**

```
$RMM = DB::table('companies')->where('branch', 'RMM')->get();
foreach ($RMM as $RMM)
{
  $post = post::find($RMM->id);//get post for each department
  if (isset($post))
    {
      $post_data[] = array('title' => $post->article_title,
                           'name' => $RMM->department.'@'.$post->author,
                           'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post->date)),
          );
    }
}
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($post_data as $key => $data)
   @foreach ($data as $item)
    <div class="col bg-light ">
     <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $item->title }}</a>
     <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $item->name }}
                                    &#64; {{$item->department}}</a>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Company**

````
    ```migrations```
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('department');
        $table->string('branch');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
````

**Post**

```
     Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id');
        $table->string('event_title')->nullable();
        $table->string('article_title')->nullable();
        $table->string('date');
        $table->string('author')->nullable();
        $table->string('article')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('file')->nullable();
        $table->string('banner_image')->nullable();;
        $table->string('gallery_image')->nullable();

        $table->index('user_id');
        $table->index('company_id');
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your models and db design?

Comment: if you have set your models correctly, you would not have done n+1 queries like these in the first place

Comment: by the way is `post` object readily available in this class?

Comment: @ThiagoValente  I editted the question.

Comment: @Ghost  Adding the migrations file.What do you mean by readily available?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are tying to access a property of a NON OBJECT as  the error says.

`item` is not an object, it's an array.

so you have to use the array access method to access its values.

```php
@foreach($post_data as $key => $data)
   @foreach ($data as $item)
    <div class="col bg-light ">
     <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $item['title'] }}</a>
     <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $item['name'] }}
                                    &#64; {{$item['department'] }}</a>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at the dump of the `$post_data` realized that you don't have to loop each element of the array again.

```php
@foreach($post_data as $key => $data)
  <div class="col bg-light ">
    <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $data['title'] }}</a>
    <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $data['name'] }}</a>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: don't forget to add `department` in the controller, the OP doesn't have it on the loop yet. but everything else here is correct, the OP has an array not a object, thus access to non existing property

Comment: but the preferred way is to have a one to many relationship configuration on the models, it eliminates having n+1 queries. these kinds of code does not scale, it may be fast on 10 or 100 entries, once you get to thousands, it really slows down

Comment: using `$item['title']` throw error " Illegal string offset 'title' " and I do use one to many relationship to these models.

Comment: @Ghost But it's not the issue here. It is an better enhancement of course. There are lot of issues in this code.

Comment: `$post_data[]` is already correct, im assuming you can have multiple articles on one company so just continually push, and remove the inner foreach loop, you do not need that, just loop on post_data and `$data['title']` and others, and add `department` index on the controller and it should solve everything

Comment: @anggor actually `$post_data` array contains earch post data object. so you don't have to run an another loop in the blade. I will update the answer.

Comment: if put ``$post_data = array();`` in iterator will be overwriter, ``$post_data[]`` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want get the title, name and date it's simple

Controller

```php
post_data = Array();
$RMM = DB::table('companies')->where('branch', 'RMM')->get();
foreach ($RMM as $RMM)
{
  $post = post::find($RMM->id);//get post for each department
  if (isset($post))
    {
      $post_data[] = array(
                        'title' => $post->article_title,
                        'name' => $RMM->department.'@'.$post->author,
                        'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post->date)),
                    );
    }
}
// You can send a array of objects
return view('example')->with('posts', $post_data);
```

View

```
@foreach($posts as $post)   
<div class="col bg-light ">
    <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $item['title'] }}</a>
    <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $item['name'] }}
                                &#64; {{$item['department']}}</a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I correct it. Thank you for all the comments and advice. Here is how I do it.
The `$post_data[]` is correct since I need to store a lot of return result from `find` function. Since, `find` already return an array of corresponding id, I do not need to put into another array, just use it as it is, as explain by @Ghost. Thus, one `foreach` enough to get the job done.

**Controller**

```
$RMM = DB::table('companies')->where('branch', 'RMM')->get();
foreach ($RMM as $RMM)
{
  $post = post::find($RMM->id);//get post for each department
  if (isset($post))
   {
     $post_data[] = $post;
   }
return view('home')->with('posts', $post_data);
}
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)   
<div class="col bg-light ">
  <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $item['title'] }}</a>
  <a class="nav-link pb-0 pt-0" href="#">{{ $item['name'] }}
                            &#64; {{$item['department']}}</a>
</div>
```

@endforeach

Answer (score 0):

**Update answer**
Another method, is to convert the array into object. The error is about non-object, directly working on it would help.

> ERROR: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object.

Alternative way

```
$RMM = DB::table('companies')->where('branch', 'RMM')->get();
foreach ($RMM as $RMM)
{
 $post = post::find($RMM->id);//get post for each department
 if (isset($post))
  {
   $post_data[] = array('title' => $post->article_title,
                       'name' => $RMM->department.'@'.$post->author,
                       'date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post->date)),
      );
  }
}
//change to object before send to blade
$object = json_decode(json_encode($post_data), FALSE);
return view('home')->with('posts', $object);
```